# Probably obvious - ImportError: No module named gtk

Tags: python, terminal, bioinformatics

I really don't know what I'm doing. I'm trying to run a bioinformatics program that I know is written in python, which I have one class worth of experience in a while ago. It requires installing a few things (Python 2.5.1, GTK+ 2.12.9 with glade support, pycairo-1.2.6-1, pygobject-2.12.3-1, pygtk-2.10.4-1, PIL-1.1.6), which I did with Terminal. Now when I try to run the program it says "ImportError: No module named gtk". It is missing the GTK+ or the pygtk? Is there a way that I can make sure that everything that I installed worked?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Ubuntu, run `sudo apt-get  -yinstall python-cairo python-gobject python-gtk2` to ensure that the packages are installed, as your error seems to indicate that the packages are not installed. Now try running that program again.

Comment: This gives me "-bash: import: command not found". Do I need to have something else installed first?

Comment: @Madison the code snippet shows how to import gtk in python, and should be run in python.

Comment: The instructions say "4. run your favourite terminal (e.g. xterm)
5. go to FociCounter's directory (e.g. cd /home/user/FociCounter)
6. type python start.py" I assumed this meant Terminal. Should I be doing this in Python instead?